# How to add values in javascript when converting from string

Tags: javascript, double, decimal

I have a string that I try to convert to a decimal number with 16 decimals. Then I like to add that number to the number 0 which should be:

```
30280.9529335
```

But I get: `030280.9529335`

How do you properly do this in javascript?

```js
var totalnumber = 0; var str = "30280.9529335";
totalnumber = totalnumber + ConvertToDouble(str);

console.log(totalnumber); //030280.9529335

function ConvertToDouble(x) {
    return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(16);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your problem is placement of `toFixed`, `toFixed` return `String` not number

```js
console.log(typeof (1).toFixed(2))
```

So here your `ConvertToDouble` function returns `string` and `0` + `some numeric string` will act as concatenation not addition

```js
var totalnumber = 0; var str = "30280.9529335";
totalnumber = totalnumber + ConvertToDouble(str);

console.log(totalnumber.toFixed(16)); //030280.9529335

function ConvertToDouble(x) {
    return Number.parseFloat(x)
}
```

Comment: It worked but I wonder: If I remove ".toFixed(16)", does it still use 16 decimals when calculating or is it Float with only 7 decimals?

Comment: @Andreas it will use only 7 decimals as it was doing previously.

Comment: @Code Maniac I see, so it is not possible to caluculate with 16 decimals at all in javascript/node.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number.parseFloat` and `Number.parseInt` similar to how you were. You used `toFixed` incorrectly.

The `toFixed()` method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.  If the desired number of decimals are higher than the actual number, nulls are added to create the desired decimal length.

> Example:

```
let a = "30280.9529335";
console.log(parseFloat(a))
// 30280.9529335
```

```js
let totalnumber = 0;
let str = "30280.9529335";

function convert(a, b) {
    try {
        return (Number.parseInt(a) + Number.parseFloat(b)).toFixed(16)
    } catch(error) {
        return error;
    }
}

function convertb(a, b) {
    try {
        return Number.parseInt(a) + Number.parseFloat(b)
    } catch(error) {
        return error;
    }
}

   console.log(convert(totalnumber, str))
   console.log(convertb(totalnumber, str))
```

You can also use `bigInts` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

```js
const theBiggestInt = 9007199254740991n;
const alsoHuge = BigInt(9007199254740991);
// ↪ 9007199254740991n
const hugeString = BigInt("9007199254740991");
// ↪ 9007199254740991n
const hugeHex = BigInt("0x1fffffffffffff");
// ↪ 9007199254740991n
const hugeBin = BigInt("0b11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
// ↪ 9007199254740991n
```

Comment: I was not sure about the .toFixed(16), I thought it returned a decimal number with 16 places. So it was a string. That makes sense to the concatenation that happened.